# Nuget - The local source does not exist

Tags: visual-studio-code, nuget

I recently cloned my OS to a new SSD, and then removed the old one once I was sure it worked.  Now, the local source is still set to the old drive, with the letter it was assigned to (E) after the cloning was complete.  I've removed every trace of "nuget" I can find on my PC and then reinstalled, but it is still set to E:, which doesn't even exist on my computer anymore.

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.401\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : The local source 'E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages' doesn't exist. [C:\Users\Jamie\Desktop\NewCode\NewCode.csproj]
```

This is a simple Hello World file.

Thanks for any help.